# Delete product from order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order

Let as assume i got 1 order that order have 10 product's after that some reason i want to **Delete** or **Cancel**  for particular product only i can keep 9 product . After Delete/cancel total also update based on product.

**i want to UI wise if admin click delete button particular product only delete from that order**

How i done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the product with sku. check this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/delete-products-from-order-programmatically)
add this function into `app\code\local\AR\Orderstatus\controllers\Adminhtml\IndexController.php`

```
public function deleteproductAction()
{
    $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');

     $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
        $items = $_order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item){
        $base_grand_total = $_order->getBaseGrandTotal();

        $base_subtotal = $_order->getBaseSubtotal();
        $base_tva = $_order->getBaseTaxAmount();

        $grand_total = $_order->getGrandTotal();

        $subtotal = $_order->getSubtotal();
        $tva = $_order->getTaxAmount();


        $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $_order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();

        $subtotal_incl_tax = $_order->getSubtotalInclTax();

        $total_item_count = $_order->getTotalItemCount();



        if($item->getProductId()==$product_id){
            $item_price = $item->getPrice();
            $item_tva = $item->getTaxAmount();
            $item->delete();
            $_order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total-$item_price-$item_tva);

            $_order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal-$item_price);

            $_order->setBaseTaxAmount($base_tva-$item_tva);

            $_order->setGrandTotal($grand_total-$item_price-$item_tva);

            $_order->setSubtotal($subtotal-$item_price);

            $_order->setTaxAmount($tva-$item_tva);


            $_order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);

            $_order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);

            $_order->setTotalItemCount(count($items)-1);

            $_order->save(); 
        }

        }
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                           ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully');
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $_order->getId()));
    }
```

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: do you  have any module because you have to add controller for that..

Comment: No module on that

Comment: did you add the delete button on product? if you added kindly add the code

Comment: No i didn't add i don't know where to add that so that

Comment: @Kothari you are asking last question first :D :D

Comment: which means????

Comment: can you tell where you want to add delete product button?

Comment: let us assume i got  1 order it have 10 product's i need each product have delete option. If i delete 1 product amount should be reduced

Comment: do you have custom requirement or creating the module?

Comment: i don't want to create module just delete option only

Comment: you want a core hack that is not recommended.

Comment: ok is there any simple module

Comment: did you using this  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93039/magento-add-new-button-on-sales-order-view

Comment: yes i am using that for add new status

Comment: go to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml` add this column before </tr> ` <td><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/deleteproduct', array('order_id' => $_item->getOrderId(),'product_id' => $_item->getProductId())) ?>">Delete</a></td>`

Comment: updated the answer. kindly apply and feedback me.

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: i got this error Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/html/2/app/code/local/AR/Orderstatus/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

Comment: update kindly check it..

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar it's working after delete i need to display some message

Comment: updated answer...

Comment: Can you please check this i have some problem in delete order http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99019/delete-product-from-the-order

Answer (score 0):

Sales > Orders > Select the Order

Select "Credit Memo" at the top, and insert the "Qty to refund" and then press Update Qty.

Once complete press the "Issue refund offline"

That will remove the product from the order.

Or are you asking how to do this without the customer knowing?

Comment: In your case first generate invoice after create credit memo for the particular product qty

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class AR
{
    public function index()    
    {
        $orderId = 100;
        $order =  Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        $removeProductSku = 'test';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $base_grand_total = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();
            $base_subtotal = $order->getBaseSubtotal();
            $base_tva = $order->getBaseTaxAmount();
            $grand_total = $order->getGrandTotal();
            $subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
            $tva = $order->getTaxAmount();
            $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
            $subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getSubtotalInclTax();
            $total_item_count = $order->getTotalItemCount();

            if($item->getSku()==$removeProductSku){
                $item_price = $item->getPrice();
                $item_tva = $item->getTaxAmount();
                $item->delete();
                $order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total-$item_price-$item_tva);
                $order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal-$item_price);
                $order->setBaseTaxAmount($base_tva-$item_tva);
                $order->setGrandTotal($grand_total-$item_price-$item_tva);
                $order->setSubtotal($subtotal-$item_price);
                $order->setTaxAmount($tva-$item_tva);
                $order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);
                $order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);
                $order->setTotalItemCount(count($items)-1);
                $order->save();
                break; 
            }
        }

}
$obj = new AR();
$obj->index();
?>
```

**Note** : first tried in demo server if working fine after use in live server

Comment: Actually i want to UI wise if admin click delete button particular product only delete from that order

Comment: Pls update your qus

Comment: Check my updated question