# Stock not updated when removing product from an order in magento Programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, inventory

I tried to remove all products from a order. All products will removed from order but quantity not revert from stock.

```
$order_id = 1010101010;
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$items = $_order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    //-- Get Order Stuff
    $base_grand_total = $_order->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $base_subtotal = $_order->getBaseSubtotal();
    $base_tva = $_order->getBaseTaxAmount();
    $grand_total = $_order->getGrandTotal();
    $subtotal = $_order->getSubtotal();
    $tva = $_order->getTaxAmount();
    $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $_order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
    $subtotal_incl_tax = $_order->getSubtotalInclTax();
    $total_item_count = $_order->getTotalItemCount();

    $item_price = $item->getPrice();
    $item_tva = $item->getTaxAmount();
    $item->delete(); //-- Remove Product 

    //-- Update Order Stuff
    $_order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total - $item_price - $item_tva);
    $_order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal - $item_price);
    $_order->setBaseTaxAmount($base_tva - $item_tva);
    $_order->setGrandTotal($grand_total - $item_price - $item_tva);
    $_order->setSubtotal($subtotal - $item_price);
    $_order->setTaxAmount($tva - $item_tva);
    $_order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax - $item_price);
    $_order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax - $item_price);
    $_order->setTotalItemCount(count($items) - 1);
    $_order->save(); //-- Save Order
}
```

I found that code on magento.stackexchange post - [Delete products from order programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/delete-products-from-order-programmatically) . I don't understand what is the problem, Can anyone please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: it because you are not updating inventory after  manually deleting the item from order

Comment: How to update inventory manually by order items. Can you please provide me sample.

Answer (score 0):

To update the qty you have to cancel order first and to Cancel order :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(12);
if ($order->canCancel()) {
    try {
    $order->cancel();

    // remove status history set in _setState
    $order->getStatusHistoryCollection(true);

    // do some more stuff here
    // ...

    $order->save();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```